# How to compare (x,y) points in array to extract rectangular shape in python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, scipy

I have a numpy array that was extracted from an image running the harris corner detection algorithm from opencv and I am trying to sort out four points that resembles a rectangle.

The following is the set of points:

```
numpy.array([[194, 438],
   [495, 431],
   [512, 519],
   [490, 311],
   [548,  28],
   [407, 194],
   [181, 698],
   [169,  93],
   [408,  99],
   [221, 251],
   [395, 692],
   [574, 424],
   [431, 785],
   [538, 249],
   [397, 615],
   [306, 237]])
```

What would be the best method to compare the points for angles in quadrants within a slight deviation of 90 along with comparing how parallel lines between top and bottom points and left and right points are to return the four best possible candidates?

**Edit**

The image is roughly aligned with the rectangle so there is no significant rotation or distortion. The deviation allowance for perspective transformation and rough capturing I think can be +/- 10 degrees

Below is an image of the plotted lines with x and y locations. The desired corners are top-left (169,93), top-right (408,99), bottom-right (395,692), and bottom-left (181,698)
[image]

Comment: are the rectangles "proper" rectangles aligned with the edges of the screen or are they rotated or distorted?

Comment: also this is going to be next-to-impossible to answer unless you tell us exactly *how* you define rectangle “goodness”. Is parallelism more important than 90 degree angles? Is a “rectangle” with one perfect 90° angle and one very bad angle better than a “rectangle” with two mediocre angles? How much?

Comment: why don't you squeeze out the extra dimension then do a scatterplot in matplotlib to get an idea of what you are working with

Comment: there are no duplicates in x or y, so no rectangles will be axis-aligned

Comment: If the angles are close to 90, the lines will be parallel. Is a method that just checks if all angles in the quadrilateral are 'close' to 90 sufficient? Are you expecting to find a near-rectangle in this image?

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more specific about the allowance in deviation from a right angle. Since there will be perspective transformation, a perfect 90 degree angle will be impossible and I think +/- 10 degrees will be ok. And the rectangle (singular) will be aligned with the image, so no rotation or distortion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the most efficient way to go about finding the corners but I split the points into four quadrants like so:

```
yThreshM = height / 2
xThreshM = width / 2

tl = dst[ ((dst[:,1]<yThreshM) & (dst[:,0]<xThreshM)) ]
tr = dst[ ((dst[:,1]<yThreshM) & (dst[:,0]>xThreshM)) ]
br = dst[ ((dst[:,1]>yThreshM) & (dst[:,0]>xThreshM)) ]
bl = dst[ ((dst[:,1]>yThreshM) & (dst[:,0]<xThreshM)) ]
```

Then I grouped each section into their respective angles for the top left and the bottom right:

```
tla = [bl, tl, tr]
bra = [tr, br, bl]

tlap = list(it.product(*tla))
brap = list(it.product(*bra))
```

Then I calculated the direction of the vertical lines and removed items not within a given perpendicular threshold. Then I calculated the angles and filtered out the items not within a threshold +/- of 90 degrees.

Lastly, I checked that the opposite end points of the results of iterating through `tlap` and `brap` matched to get the rest of the points and to verify the `tl` and `br` points.